# Automatic JAX-RX to RAML

Tags: java, web-services, maven, resteasy, raml

I have written web services of my Java project using resteasy. For the documentation process i want these web services to be captured using RAML.

For this I am able to find an eclipse plugin of RAML that will generate a .raml file. But we have to do this manually, i.e. click on class file or package to generate raml files.

So my question is - isn't there a way by which all the classes that are for web services or under a package, a raml file be generated during packaging of the project.

Say using maven during the build process.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is: https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs

`RAML for JAX-RS` has both `RAML → JAX-RS` and `JAX-RS → RAML` Maven plug-ins, the latter being what you're looking for.

Comment: Using the doc you specified and https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/blob/master/maven-plugin.md

Following all the steps that are specified i get this error when i package my project

[ERROR] Plugin org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.raml:jaxrs-to-raml:pom:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT in Nexus-One (http://mvn-repo/nexus/content/groups/One/) -> [Help 1]

Can you suggest.

Comment: using 1.3.3 solves the above problem but gives me another error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.3:generate-raml (default) on project spectralight: Execution default of goal org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.3:generate-raml failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.3:generate-raml: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mulesoft.jaxrs.raml.annotation.model.IParameterModel.getType()Ljava/lang/String;
Please can you suggest for this too.

Comment: I started to look at the class files of com.mulesoft.jaxrs.raml.annotation package and came to know that the method that it says getType() does not exists in IParameterModel interface. Instead there is a method getParameterType(). So the above error i am getting seems to be correct.
Now the question is which version to be used as in 1.3.3 that method is missing.

Please correct me if i am wrong. Or is there some other way to solve this.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, this used to work fine. Please open an issue for the project maintainers here: https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I have filed an issue on github. Just in case you want to follow it here is the link - https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/issues/140